# How to cast left side value in Ansible/Jinja selectattr filter condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm working in Ansible 2.9.13 on Python 3.8.4

In an Ansible playbook, I have a list of dictionaries, and I want to loop on just the subset of items that have a pct_used value of greater than 90.

Here's a playbook that illustrates it:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    usage_records: [{mount: "/abc", pct_used: "50"}, {mount: "/def", pct_used: "75"}, {mount: "/ghi", pct_used: "95"}]
  tasks:
    - name: process just records with more than 90 percent usage
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ usage_records|selectattr('pct_used','ge', 90)|list }}"
```

But if I run this, it complains about the fact that the pct_used values are AnsibleUnicode strings and not ints:

```
TASK [process just records with more than 90 percent usage] ************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ usage_records|selectattr('pct_used','ge', 90)|list }}): '>=' not supported between instances of 'AnsibleUnicode' and 'int'"}
```

Now, I realize the issue is that the pct_used value in the dictionary is a string and not an int.  If I re-write the usage_records definition row without the quotes around the numbers:

```
    usage_records: [{mount: "/abc", pct_used: 50}, {mount: "/def", pct_used: 75}, {mount: "/ghi", pct_used: 95}]
```

it does work as expected:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'mount': '/ghi', 'pct_used': 95}) => {
    "msg": {
        "mount": "/ghi",
        "pct_used": 95
    }
}
```

The problem is that in my actual use case, the data is being read in from a file and is all strings by default, so I can't change it at the source.

I feel like there must be a way to do the cast in the filter expression in the loop, but I just can't figure it out.

If that's NOT possible, what's the best way to update the list itself to cast the values to ints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution that's cleaner for my purposes. Apparently you can use both a loop and a when clause, and the when clause can reference the loop variable. The when clause gives some more flexibility with the logic.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    usage_records: [{mount: "/abc", pct_used: 50}, {mount: "/def", pct_used: 75}, {mount: "/ghi", pct_used: 95}]
  tasks:
    - name: process just records with more than 90 percent usage
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      when: item.pct_used|int >= 90
      loop: "{{ usage_records }}"
```

Still gets the desired output:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'mount': '/ghi', 'pct_used': 95}) => {
    "msg": {
        "mount": "/ghi",
        "pct_used": 95
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's one option:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    usage_records:
      - mount: "/abc"
        pct_used: "50"
      - mount: "/def"
        pct_used: "75"
      - mount: "/ghi"
        pct_used: "95"
  tasks:
    - name: process just records with more than 90 percent usage
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: >-
        {{ usage_records|zip(
            usage_records|
            map(attribute='pct_used')|
            map('int')
          )|
          selectattr('1', 'ge', 90)|list
        }}
```

This results in:

```
TASK [process just records with more than 90 percent usage] ***********************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'mount': '/ghi', 'pct_used': '95'}, 95]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "mount": "/ghi",
            "pct_used": "95"
        },
        95
    ]
}
```

Here we're using to invocations of `map` to (a) create a second list consisting of just the `pct_used` values, and then (b) passing these all through the `int` filter. Finally, we `zip` together the original list with our new list. This gives us a final list where each item consists of the dictionary from the first list followed by the integer value from the second list (which we can use for filtering).

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution, and it definitely does work, but it's a little more complicated than I was hoping for. I can imagine that there might be scenarios where something like this might be necessary for someone, so it's good to have it here as a reference. I just think I found something a little cleaner. In retrospect, I think I was overthinking my question.